# Scaling CGPatternRef dynamically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Hey, I've got a view with some items I lay out in it, and a tiled background image. I've set it's backgroundColor to a CGPatternRef. I am trying to get it so I can scale the background image in tandem with the contents in my layer. I've got the background image scaling fine, I just can't seem to figure out how to make it update when the scale changes. Here is my drawCallback

```
static void drawPatternImage (void *info, CGContextRef ctx)
{
    CGImageRef image = (CGImageRef) info;
    CGContextDrawTiledImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0, CGImageGetWidth(image)*scaleValue, CGImageGetHeight(image)*scaleValue), image);
}
```

the image is drawn how I expect, but when I change the scale value, and then call setNeedsDisplay on my layer, the callback method isn't called again, and my background isn't updated. Is this the best way to approach this problem? Or is there a more efficient way of drawing a scalable tileable image in my view. I implemented **- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx** and called CGContextDrawTiledImage from in there, but when scaling my view, the updating was very choppy.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CGPattern needs to know the size of the pattern, you pass that in your call to `CGPatternCreate`. Just drawing in a different size in you callback isn't going to help, so you must destroy and re-setup the pattern, passing the new size to `CGPatternCreate`.